# PL/SQL convert string to number

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, converters

I want to convert a string to numbers for a checksum. The string consists of  universityCode || ' ' || countryCode || ' ' || studentNumber.

An example string could be:

> TUE NL 123456789

I have to convert this sample string to numbers, and tried this with the TO_NUMBER function, but I keep getting an error.

This is my code to create (or replace) a function in PL/SQL:

```
-- Een functie om een International Student Identification Number (ISIN) te genereren
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generateISIN(
  countryCode Country.Code%TYPE,
  universityCode University.Code%TYPE,
  studentNumber VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  newStudentNumber VARCHAR2(50) := '';
BEGIN
-- Zorgen voor de goede waarde voordat we de checksum beginnen
newStudentNumber := universityCode || ' ' || countryCode || ' ' || studentNumber;
-- newStudentNumber omzetten naar enkel getallen
newStudentNumber := TO_NUMBER(newStudentNumber);
-- Spaties weghalen in newStudentNumber
newStudentNumber := TRIM(' ' FROM newStudentNumber);
  RETURN newStudentNumber;
END;
/
```

Could someone help me with my problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What result are you expecting when you convert this string to a number? Should the number be 123456789 or something else?

Comment: @BobJarvis I thought that all chars would be converted to a number, but my assignment description says A =16, B=17, C=18, ...

Comment: You'll need to convert it character-by-character then, using whatever mapping you've been given; presumably with even numeric digits mapped somehow. Depending on the rules you might be able to use an offset from ASCII for some characters, but not all. And then presumably sum the numeric value for each character, if this is for a checksum?

Comment: So what value should be used for a blank?

Comment: @BobJarvis First I need to convert every character to a number, than I have to delete all blank spaces

Comment: OK. So once you convert every character to a number and delete all the blank spaces, then what..?

Comment: @BobJarvis Than I have to make groups of 4 numbers, followed by a space. The last group can consist of 1,2,3 or 4 numbers. Than I need to put the string in reverse order, remove all blank spaces again and divide the number by 62... see this link for a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/6zkn3h

Comment: OK, so you need to try to convert that algorithm into PL/SQL code. The to_number function isn't relevant. I think you should try to implement the logic, see if you can make it work, and if not come back and ask about specific problems with what you're doing. Asking us to write it for you - especially with unclear requirements - isn't going to help you really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're supposed to convert the initial string, which may/will contain alphabetic characters, to another string containing only numeric characters. Then you've got some other messing around to do, but the following may get you started:

```
FUNCTION CONVERT_STR_TO_NUMERIC(pin_Str IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  strResult  VARCHAR2(32767);
  c          CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(pin_Str) LOOP
    c := SUBSTR(pin_Str, i, 1);

    strResult := strResult || CASE c
                                WHEN 'A' THEN '16'
                                WHEN 'B' THEN '17'
                                WHEN 'C' THEN '18'
                                WHEN 'D' THEN '19'
                                WHEN 'E' THEN '20'
                                WHEN 'F' THEN '21'
                                WHEN 'G' THEN '22'
                                WHEN 'H' THEN '23'
                                WHEN 'I' THEN '24'
                                WHEN 'J' THEN '25'
                                WHEN 'K' THEN '26'
                                WHEN 'L' THEN '27'
                                WHEN 'M' THEN '28'
                                WHEN 'N' THEN '29'
                                WHEN 'O' THEN '30'
                                WHEN 'P' THEN '31'
                                WHEN 'Q' THEN '32'
                                WHEN 'R' THEN '33'
                                WHEN 'S' THEN '34'
                                WHEN 'T' THEN '35'
                                WHEN 'U' THEN '36'
                                WHEN 'V' THEN '37'
                                WHEN 'W' THEN '38'
                                WHEN 'X' THEN '39'
                                WHEN 'Y' THEN '40'
                                WHEN 'Z' THEN '41'
                                ELSE c
                              END;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN strResult;
END CONVERT_STR_TO_NUMERIC;
```

For example, if you call the above with your test string of 'TUE NL 123456789' it produces '353620 2927 123456789'.

Comment: As I discovered today I could also use the ASCII method and do that numer -49

Comment: Can I also reverse this function? That I generate letters from numbers (instead of numbers from letters)?

Comment: Perhaps. One problem to overcome would be knowing whether a string of numbers should be converted to ASCII or left alone. I'm not sure how you'd know that, but perhaps you can figure something out. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

can you not just use

```
SQL> select ora_hash( "mycode" )  from dual;

ORA_HASH('mycode')
----------------------
            2519249214
```

Comment: Not if the assignment specifies the algorithm to use, as the comments suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I found this and it works perfectly:

```
string VARCHAR2(50) := '';
temp VARCHAR2(50) := '';

for i in 1..length(string) loop
        temp := temp||(ascii(substr(string,i,1))-ascii('A')+16);  
     end loop;
```